# What does the "nonland" restriction mean?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My brother says that [Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d) allows you to play any card from your hand without paying any mana.

I thought "nonland" meant anything with no colored mana cost?

Comment: I tried to interpret the question as well as I could, but you still don't really ask for anything in particular. If the answers below don't already answer your question, please clarify what you want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Magic 2013 version of the card says

> You may cast nonland cards from your hand without paying their mana costs.

That's not actually the current official text of the card (see Gatherer: [Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d)), it currently says:

> You may cast spells from your hand without paying their mana costs.

But those basically mean the same thing: you may cast *any card that is not a land card*. They have to write that, because lands are *played*, not cast, and playing a land never has a mana cost anyway.

So you can cast cards with colored mana costs, cards with only colored mana costs, anything you want. You can even cast cards that don't have a mana cost at all (that can't be cast normally), like [Living End](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLiving%20End%5d).

But not lands.

Also the normal timing restrictions apply, so you can still play sorceries only during your own main phase when the stack is empty, and also if a card has additional costs besides mana, you still have to pay that too.

Comment: I seem to recall this site has some way to turn card names into Gatherer links, but I can't remember how.

Comment: You can use the `[mtg:Card Name]` syntax in posts, but i won't show up in the preview.

Answer (score 4):

The text of the card states that

> You may cast spells from your hand without paying their mana costs.

In regard to the nonland ruling, nonland simply means any card that is not a land. There are restrictions however. If a card has an {X} symbol in its casting cost and is played with Omniscience, X must be zero.

Answer (score 2):

*Nonland* (and other phrases like it, such as *noncreature*) simply refers to the card type, meaning the effect only applies to cards that don't have the Land type, or more generally speaking, "are not lands".

It doesn't state anything about color or color identity derived from the mana cost - effects that do (such as *Devotion* will explicitly state this). I suppose this fallacy is based on lands usually being colorless, though [Dryad Arbor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDryad%20Arbor%5d), for example, is a green land and proves that this is not a correct assumption.

---

[Omniscience](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOmniscience%5d) allows you to cast spells from your hand without paying their mana cost. Lands can't be cast as spells, so probably to prevent misunderstandings, the original version of the card said "nonland cards" (this has since been errata'd).